# Rendering problem in JSF 1.1

Tags: jsf

We are using JSF 1.1 Myfaces 1.1.3 and mixing of html elements.
 For Ex:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<P>PAGE 1</P>
<h:outputText value="packs" style="padding-left:5%; font-weight:bold" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But what happens sometimes is that, the page is not rendering properly to the user (Nothing is shown to the user) so we have used  tag in between the HTML Elements like

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<f:verbatim><P>PAGE 1</P></f:verbatim>
<h:outputText value="packs" style="padding-left:5%; font-weight:bold" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But this is also not helped and we are still facing the same problem.

So what i want to know is,
1.Is this the limitation in JSF 1.1 ?
2.If not what will be the workaround to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have imported the custom tag libraries into your JSPs:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
```

Verify that you have included the [view](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/tlddocs/f/view.html) tags:

```
<f:view>
  <HTML>
    <!-- etc. -->
```